# What is the type of object when I do a map in a pipe on an observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am sort of lost in the **observable pipe map** space.

I have found this example:

```
 of(1,2,3).pipe(
            map(x => x + 1),

          );
```

In this sample,  x is a number (I guess it's 1 then 2 then 3)

Now in this (part of) my code:

```
 let src : SearchResultsFilter[] = [];
        let source = of(src);
        source.pipe(map(u => u.))
```

I would have guessed `u` is a `SearchResultsFilter`, but it is of type `SearchResultsFilter[]`.

So now I'm lost. I thought `map` iterates through all of the items in the collection you put the pipe on, but somewhere I've lost it apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `of(src)`.

`of` takes each argument and just reemits it. So when you use `of(1, 2, 3)` it takes `1`, `2` and `3` and thus makes three separate emissions. So in your case using `of(src)` is the same as using `of([1, 2, 3])` which emits the entire array as one emission.

Instead of `of(src)` you might want to use `from(src)` that iterates `src` and emits each item in that array as a separate emission which is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to get my head around this rxjs, this helps!